# Binding same property to two paths in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, multibinding

I have a graph control that has two types of entities: Nodes and Edges (Links).
The graph control exposes a couple of properties namely

- myGraphContol.SeletedNode
- myGraphControl.SelectedLink

Both the Nodes and edges have some profile data for visualization hence they both implement an interface called IProfile.

The profile data would be visualized in an adjoining ContentControl which would pick up the appropriate template.
This works perfectly fine:

```
<ContentControl VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ContentTemplate="{Binding Source={StaticResource AllPropertiesTemplate}}" Content="{Binding Path=SelectedNode.Data,ElementName=myGraphContol}"/>
```

But how do I make it work for another property SelectedLink.Data. Basically the content control has to be bound with both the properties. The user would click either a node or an edge any one at a time and be able to view the profile.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks for reaing this.

regards,

Comment: You can use multibinding, but maybe it would be better to genericize your selected item so that both a selected node or edge can be represented by the same property.

Comment: Can you please provide a pointer to multibinding way of doing this. In multibinding a converter is a must.

Comment: I see a number of related posts on the right give very good answers on how multibinding works and how to set it up. It's effectively the same as a binding, you just add multiple bindings to it.
This site has a good example of something similar to what you'd want to do.
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-multibindings

Answer (score 0):

The ContentControl has only a single Content element so you can either:

1. Nest the two properties in an encapsulating object or
2. Create a Custom Control with two (or more) properties that can be bound.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is a third party control and I cannt make changes in it :(